# Is there a way to configure the 'Stack Name' of nested stacks in AWS cloudformation ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a nested stack using AWS CloudFormation. 
I need to specify the 'Stack Name' of the nested stack. 
I tried using the 'Tags' property with Key: 'Stack Name'. But that didn't help.
Is there any way to provide the Stack Name as an input while creating nested stack?

Comment: Why do you "need to specify the 'Stack Name' of the nested stack"? Understanding that may help us find the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In a given template, you have access to the pseudo-parameters stackId and stackName. Those can be marked for export, then referenced in another stack. Joined, they give you the child stack's name.

I found the following video quite useful despite its age: https://youtu.be/6R44BADNJA8

This sample template may also be helpful in understanding how these work: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/user-guide/cross-stack/SampleNetworkCrossStack.template

```
{ "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09", "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template VPC_with_PublicIPs_And_DNS: Sample template that creates a VPC with DNS and public IPs enabled. Note that you are billed for the AWS resources that you use when you create a stack from this template.", "Resources" : { "VPC" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC", "Properties" : { "EnableDnsSupport" : "true", "EnableDnsHostnames" : "true", "CidrBlock" : "10.0.0.0/16" } }, "PublicSubnet" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet", "Properties" : { "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }, "CidrBlock" : "10.0.0.0/24" } }, "InternetGateway" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway" }, "VPCGatewayAttachment" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment", "Properties" : { "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }, "InternetGatewayId" : { "Ref" : "InternetGateway" } } }, "PublicRouteTable" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::RouteTable", "Properties" : { "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" } } }, "PublicRoute" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Route", "DependsOn" : "VPCGatewayAttachment", "Properties" : { "RouteTableId" : { "Ref" : "PublicRouteTable" }, "DestinationCidrBlock" : "0.0.0.0/0", "GatewayId" : { "Ref" : "InternetGateway" } } }, "PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation", "Properties" : { "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" }, "RouteTableId" : { "Ref" : "PublicRouteTable" } } }, "PublicSubnetNetworkAclAssociation" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation", "Properties" : { "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" }, "NetworkAclId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["VPC", "DefaultNetworkAcl"] } } }, "WebServerSecurityGroup" : { "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup", "Properties" : { "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP ingress", "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }, "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" } ] } } }, "Outputs" : { "VPCId" : { "Description" : "VPC ID", "Value" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }, "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID" }} }, "PublicSubnet" : { "Description" : "The subnet ID to use for public web servers", "Value" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" }, "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetID" }} }, "WebServerSecurityGroup" : { "Description" : "The security group ID to use for public web servers", "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["WebServerSecurityGroup", "GroupId"] }, "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SecurityGroupID" }} } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented below, the answer is no for now.

Original:Yes, it's the resource name that gets taken as the stack name. Below you'd get a stack called myStackName

YAML

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  myStackName: 
Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
Properties: 
  TemplateURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/EC2ChooseAMI.template"
  Parameters: 
    InstanceType: "t1.micro"
    KeyName: "mykey"
```

JSON

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
   "Resources" : {
  "myStackName" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
     "Properties" : {
        "TemplateURL" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/EC2ChooseAMI.template",
        "Parameters" : {
           "InstanceType" : "t1.micro",
           "KeyName" : "mykey"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this way. But the child stack's name is generated like `ParentStackName-ResourceName-UniqueID` and not just the Resource name. For example, if the parent stack name is My-Service and the resource name is my-resource, the nested stack's name is like `My-Service-my-resource-IHTJ**JKT`

Comment: @Neethu I'm afraid that is the way AWS have made it work at the moment and there isn't an alternative I'm aware of. A lot of CF resource names are derived in that way including ECS clusters and ALB targets, they don't have their own name parameter. Hopefully that will change.

Comment: So the answer is "No", for now.